# Создание словаря из двумерного массива / кортежа

Tags: python, массивы

у меня есть двумерный массив/кортеж
`new_mas = [("Коля",5),("Слава",3),("Саня",4)]`. Я хочу получить из него только `3,4,5` с привязкой по ключу

Comment: Вы ходите получить словарь `{'Коля': 5, 'Слава': 3, 'Саня': 4}` ?

Comment: да словарь, и как выводить по ключу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 new_dict = { k:v for k,v in new_mas }
```

Значение по ключу:

```
 new_dict["Слава"]
```

Comment: смотри мне приходят такие данные `[(somecode, 'test.png'),(somecode, 'cat.png')]`
и когда я пишу `new_dict['cat.png']` выдает ошибку(без кавычек тоже) `KeyError: 'cat.png'`

Comment: @Womba306 А обратный словарь вам никто не обещал. У вас словарь вида `new_dict[somecode]`.   Если нужен обратный, то `new_dict = { k:v for v,k in new_mas }` (k и v поменяны местами).

Comment: тоесть я ищу по `somecode`

Comment: А все теперь заработало. Спасибо))))))

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то элементарно:

```
new_dict = dict(new_mas)
```

И в `new_dict` получится словарь вида:

```
{'Коля': 5, 'Слава': 3, 'Саня': 4}
```

Ну и "обратный" словарь:

```
new_dict = dict(map(reversed, new_mas))
```

```
{5: 'Коля', 3: 'Слава', 4: 'Саня'}
```

Comment: смотри мне приходят такие данные [(somecode, 'test.png'),(somecode, 'cat.png')] и когда я пишу new_dict['cat.png'] выдает ошибку(без кавычек тоже) KeyError: 'cat.png'

Comment: @Womba306 А обратный словарь вам никто не обещал. У вас словарь вида `new_dict[somecode]`.